# SQL Check Constraint Date of birth

Tags: sql, constraints

```
CREATE TABLE  "CUSTOMER" 

("CUS_ID" VARCHAR2(9), 
"NAME" VARCHAR2(30), 
"EMAIL" VARCHAR2(30), 
"BIRTH_DATE" DATE, 
"Mobile_number" NUMBER (10),
"Number_adopted" (number) (1),
 CONSTRAINT "CUSTOMER_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CUS_ID")
 constraint "Email_uni" unique (EMAIL)
 constraint "Mobile_uni" unique (Mobile_number)
 constraint adopted_range_ck check ( Number_adopted >=1 and Number_adopted<=4) USING INDEX  ENABLE
);
```

I want to create a constraint where a customer cannot be younger than 18.

Comment: You can refer this link to create constraint on date https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424900/check-constraint-on-date-of-birth

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with a `check` constraint in Oracle.  As defined in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52163):

> Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following constructs:
>
> - Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions
> - Calls to the functions that are not deterministic (CURRENT_DATE,
>     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, DBTIMEZONE, LOCALTIMESTAMP, SESSIONTIMEZONE,
>     SYSDATE, SYSTIMESTAMP, UID, USER, and USERENV)

You need some notion of the current time to calculate the age.

This is because Oracle treats check constraints more seriously than some other databases do.  They validate the data "forever", not just when the data is loaded into the table.

You can do what you want with a trigger.

Comment: Can you share how to do it with a trigger?